# How to delay sequence emitting in Rxjs

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have an observable:

```
  messages: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  const source = from(messages)
```

How do you delay it so when anyone subscribes to it, it will delay for n second to emit the items?
So:

```
source.subscribe(i => console.log(i));
// output  ...n seconds... 'a' ...n seconds... 'b' ...n seconds... 'c'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine the stream with an interval using `zip`:

```
zip(
  from(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
  interval(1000),
  (a, b) => a
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

`zip` would combine the nth elements of the each stream into an array. That's way we use a selector function: `(a, b) => a`. It ensures that only elements from the first stream are used. The `interval` stream is only used for delaying emission.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I solved it as the following code

```js
const {from, of} = rxjs;
const {concatMap, delay} = rxjs.operators;

from(['a', 'b', 'c'])
   .pipe(concatMap((msg) => of(msg).pipe(delay(1000))))
   .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `.delay()` operator:

```
messages: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const source = from(messages).pipe(
    delay(1000)//delay for 1 second
)
```

Remember to import `delay`:

```
import { delay } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
```

Comment: Thanks for the editing, my english sucks. Your answers is not what I want since it will delay for 1 second for every elements:  `1 seconds ... a b c`, but I want to delay for 1 second per elements: `...n seconds... 'a' ...n seconds... 'b' ...n seconds... 'c'`

Answer (score 0):

```
const source = from(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
const delayPerElements = source
  .pipe(map(v => of(v).pipe(delay(1000))), concatAll());
delayPerElements.subscribe(it => console.log(it));
// ... a ... b ... c ... d
```

I don't know if this is the best way but it works for me. Hope this help someone in the future.

As @Igno Burk suggestion:

```
const source = from(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
const delayPerElements = source
  .pipe(concatMap(v => of(v).pipe(delay(1000))));
delayPerElements.subscribe(it => console.log(it));
// ... a ... b ... c ... d
return delayPerElements;
```

Comment: Instead of map + concatAll, just use concatMap.

Comment: It somewhat works in this simple example but it doesn't really do what you want. It holds one element back for one second, then the rest of the pipeline processes the element, which takes time as well. So we don't have a stable interval.